# run program opengl in C# using framework Tao in 64 bits

Tags: c#, opengl, tao-framework

I have a program opengl in C# using framework Tao,
when i run the code in the platform target to x86, i have not a problem,but when i run the code in the platform target to x32, it stops abruptly and says the following

"An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)"

Advice what to do because i need to run my program in 64 bits

Comment: Should that be 'when I run the code with the platform target as x64' ie x64 not x32?

Comment: The HRESULT indicates it's trying to load a dll with the wrong 'bitnes', google shows a few results for this error for people on 64bit platforms.

Answer (score 0):

My gut feeling is that the Tao library is 64bit, if your program is compiled at 32bit, it can't link to 64bit lobs, even running on a 64bit machine.  At least not without a thinking layer and you don't want that in a graphics loop.

Comment: That or the library was built to target x86 and doesn't like being called as a pure x64, if bob is correct!